# Windows 8 apps, after uninstalling whole app folder and data still resides?

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, windows-store-app

I have just completed a fresh install of my new laptop with windows 8 as it came with a load of pre-installed rubbish.

After deleting the apps that are pre-installed on any windows 8 install, I navigated to the where the apps are stored.

You can do this by going to your program folder and while viewing hidden folders there should be a folder called `WindowsApps`. To gain access to it you have to manually assign yourself the ownership of the folder and contents.

Upon gaining access I noticed that all and every app I have ever used still resides in the folder, whether installed and then uninstalled. Why is this? I would have thought after an uninstall of an app it would have removed that app completely from the system?

How can I in the future make sure that the app is properly uninstalled (I hate having left over files), would it be safe to delete the folders of a currently uninstalled app?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just delete them and find out?  Just make a backup first if you're worried.  Are you finding apps you downloaded yourself in there, or only the apps that come default with Windows 8?

Comment: @techie007 all apps go there, and after an uninstall the whole app still remains there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `DISM /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage` to kill the preinstalled apps. this can be done online (running Windows) or offlne (with an mounted WIM).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh852635.aspx